# Security in front-end applications

Tags: javascript, angular, security, authentication, frontend

I'm new to anything to do with user authentication in general, both front and backend. I'm building an application with Angular 2/5. I've found [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) by Jason Watmore that I will try to adapt for my needs. I see in the comments, Jason explains that for sites where you want the front-end to be secure, it is advisable to do authentication in a separate front-end app, and then redirect the user to the full app, once the user has logged in. The reason being that no front-end app is secure, in that a user could alter variables to view routes that are protected by route guards, or other ways. That data is still secure from the back-end, but you have features you don't want the public knowing about in the front-end, like how you are analyzing data entered by users.

My question is, in regards securing a front-end application, is this an absolute truth that it isn't possible? It makes sense, and I have a hunch it is true, but I was wondering if there are ways to at least make it very difficult to view guarded routes. (Like the route guard asks the server if the token is valid?... But then you could just mod the function to always return true, right? Hmm...)

[Edit] Could lazy loading come into play here? Would it be possible to build a module/route that the server only makes available once the user has logged in?

Comment: There's no security in client-side code. It can be unobfuscated, modified and tampered by a user. What objective is lazy loadng supposed to solve?

Comment: If a lazy-loaded route/module was protected by the server, and only available to users with privileges after authentication, then it would not be possible to tamper with it by a non-privileged user... But I don't know if this is standard at all. I can't be the first person who's thought of it.

Comment: Again, there's no security. Once a user obtains 'protected' scripts (from someone else's browser cache), he/she's able to tamper them. How do you expect it to affect the app any way? All access control should be performed by API. You can restrict the access to some scripts on server side, but this will restrict you from serving them as regular static files or deploying to CDN. The best thing you can do is to restrict access to .map files if you don't want your code be (easily) rev-engineered and stolen.

Comment: Are you saying that is it not possible to prevent the server from serving a file under certain condition like authentication? Because that is all I am looking for. It doesn't matter that a hacker could gain access to the file from someone else who has authenticated and accessed the resource.

Comment: It's certainly possible. I'm saying that nobody does that because it is impractical and doesn't really make sense. I had same idea many years ago. I guess most of us had. It's just an obstacle to server architecture that doesn't have any real benefits.

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/mean-stack-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial This tutorial contains a solution to a problem. The application should only be available to those who have authenticated. The solution here was build the login separate from the main app, and redirect to it after login. This is a pretty common way of handling this problem. This is just as impractical as my idea. Would you say this is a waste of time?

Comment: Having two different apps is more cumbersome but reasonable way to handle this, because it won't have architectural issues. Frontend app contains auth form. Redirect url is retrieved from API on auth. Browser redirects to backend app. Notice that this is not *security*, because 'security through obscurity' doesn't work and should never be relied on. The purpose is restrict regular users from accidentally peeking at backend features, because it's none of their business.

Comment: The example I sent redirects to a front-end app, not backend. I'm not talking about obscuring anything at this point, but entirely preventing parts from being served.

Comment: The apps can be named whatever you like. In the example I've described 'backend' Angular app is restricted, and 'frontend' Angular is public. In your example 'frontend' is restricted, and there's no public Angular app for login at all, it's just static html form. The problem is possibly in the reasons why you want to prevent them from being served. This shouldn't be done for security purposes, because there shouldn't be anything in client side code that could impose security problems. While 'peeking' problem is real and can be addressed (but not by preventing script from being served).

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I only want to prevent unauthorized users from seeing *how* we are analyzing data from the server. So access to the templates would be a problem. It's not that there are things in the client side that are security problems.

Comment: If client side code contains something that can be considered sensitive (proprietary algorithms, etc), the proper way to approach the problem is to obfuscate it to the point when it cannot be useful. If this is not enough, sensitive code should be moved to server side, at least partially. As it was said, preventing JS files from being served will prevent server infrastructure from evolving when the project grows. Deployment process may become tricky. These static files cannot be cached by reverse proxy, which is default way to optimize performance. They cannot be deployed to CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very reasonable thought to try and protect some front-end code from unauthenticated users, and lazy loading may in fact help with that.

A few thoughts:

- Only allowing certain (authenticated) users to download certain front-end files does increase security by making such code impossible to analyse for potential external attackers. So people not having credentials will have a harder time finding things like XSS in those parts of the application, which is an actual security benefit.
- Something similar can be achieved by obfuscation, but obviously, that will never be so good as never giving away the code to unauthenticated users.
- Doing this will make development (the process) in general a lot more complex, and complexity is not usually a good friend of security.
- A lot of the attackers are not external. Having sensitive information in client-side code is not a good idea, and business logic can very much be sensitive by itself. Any valid user of the application can become an "attacker", and they will need to have this code if it's on the client.
- So therefore, the best practice is to place such business logic on the server.
- But ultimately, it's based on the risk you want to take. Factors that need to be considered include the price (amount of resources) of putting it all on the server, the potential loss if this info is lost to an adversary, the likelihood of that happening (ie. are there 5 trusted users, or 150000 unknown ones), and your risk appetite.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between front-end code and back-end is that front-end is run on the computer of whoever is visiting the website, whereas back-end is run on a server usually hundreds of miles away. If it's front-end code, that means its on the users computer, which means they have access to it. You can be sneaky and make it so that only a knowledgable "hacker" can actually see anything important, but it's impossible to hide front-end code. Their computer needs it, therefore the user has access to it.

Comment: Very familiar with the concept of front and backend code. Just as someone who's never integrated security/authentication, I'd never had to think about it in regards to that. But yeah, this makes total sense. Thanks.

Comment: I added to my question about lazy loading. Seems like you would be able to protect part of your application in a lazy-loaded module, if you could protect that module on the backend.